# Page reload on a form submit! Rails API backend Javascript frontend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble figuring out my javascript. The e.preventDefault() is not working. I've tried changing the submit input to a button as well. I know with a form and using rails that it has an automatic rage reload but I thought e.preventDefault was suppose to stop that. Is there some hidden feature in the backend that I need to turn off? I set my project up to be an api by using an api flag. It also has all the right info for cors. My server is showing my data correctly ...it's just the frontend I cant get up.

I'm going to post a sample code I followed.

````
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>

    <title>Problems</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="src/user.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="src/problem.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

   <div class="container" id="container">

    <h1>Everyone Has Problems</h1>

        <div id="new-user-and-new-problem-container">
            <form id="new-user-form">
                <label>Your name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="new-user-body"/>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="problems-container" class="problems-container">
    </div>

  </body>

</html>```

src/user.js
```document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    User.createUser()
})

class User {

    constructor(user){
        this.id = user.id
        this.name = user.name
        this.problems = user.problems
    }

    static createUser(){
        let newUserForm = document.getElementById('new-user-form')
        newUserForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log(e);
                fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users', {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Accept": "application/json"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(
                        {
                            user: {
                                name: e.target.children[1].value
                            }
                        })
                    })
                        .then(resp =>  {
                            return resp.json()
                        })
                        .then(user => {
                            let newUser = new User(user)
                            newUser.displayUser()
                        })
        })
    }

    displayUser() {
        let body = document.getElementById('container')
        body.innerHTML = ''
        let userGreeting = document.createElement('p')
        userGreeting.setAttribute('data-id', this.id)
        let id = userGreeting.dataset.id
        userGreeting.innerHTML = `<h1>Hey, ${this.name}!</h1>`
        body.append(userGreeting)
        if (this.problems) {
            this.problems.forEach(function(problem){
                let newProblem = new Problem(problem)
                newProblem.appendProblem()
            })
        }
        Problem.newProblemForm(this.id)
    }

}```

src/problem.js
```class Problem {

    constructor(problem){
        this.id = problem.id
        this.name = problem.name
        this.description = problem.description
    }

    static newProblemForm(user_id) {
        let body = document.getElementById('container')
        let form = 
            `
                <form id="new-problem-form">
                    <label>What's your problem?:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="problem-name"/>
                    <label>Describe it:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="problem-description"/>
                    <input type="submit"/>
                    <h4>Your current problems:</h4>
                </form>
            `
        body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', form)
        Problem.postProblem(user_id)
    }

    //is it appropriate for this to be a static method?
    static postProblem(user_id) {
        let newForm = document.getElementById('new-problem-form')
        newForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/problems', {
                method: "POST",
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        problem: {
                            name: e.target.children[1].value,
                            description: e.target.children[3].value,
                            user_id: user_id
                        }
                    }
                )
            })
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(json => {
                let newProblem = new Problem(json)
                newForm.reset()
                newProblem.appendProblem()

            })
        })
    }

    appendProblem(){
        let problems = document.getElementsByClassName('problems-container')
        let li = document.createElement('li')
        li.setAttribute('data-id', this.id)
        li.setAttribute('style', "list-style-type:none")
        li.innerHTML = `${this.name} ~~ ${this.description}`
        let solveForm = `<button type="button" id="${this.id}" class="solve-problem"> Solve </button>`
        li.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', solveForm)
        problems[0].append(li)
        let button = document.getElementById(`${this.id}`)
        this.solve(button)
    }

    solve(button){
        button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/problems/${e.target.parentNode.dataset.id}`, {
                    method: "DELETE"
            })
                    e.target.parentElement.remove();
        })
    }

}```
````

Comment: Another weird thing. If I open a server on another project but open this html that is posted it doesn't refresh.... but it obviously cant load the data because it's a server to another project.

Comment: If you don't want your page to reload, why not just use AJAX?  It specializes in requesting data without page reload.

Comment: It’s for a project for school. We are required to use fetch :/

Answer (score 0):

Try not splitting the element up.

```
document.getElementById('new-problem-form').
  addEventListener('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
  }
```

even Jquery

```
$('#new-problem-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
});
```

The preventDefault is working on the event..
Take this for example:

```
 $('#message').keydown(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
  });
```

This is preventing the enter key from defaulting the submit based on the keydown function.  Is this option the actual 'default' you're trying to stop?

Comment: Ok I will try this! Thanks! I even tried testing some fetch calls with another api and it works fine. It’s just mine that’s not working. Not sure if it’s user error or my Mac. I set the backend up how I always do ‍♀️